# Nginx/Passenger/Rails, where to set RAILS_ENV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I've deployed my site to its testing location, but I'm not sure where I set what the `RAILS_ENV` should be for this server. Where should I look?

Answer (score 40):

Short Answer:     **passenger_app_env development;**

Sets:
**RAILS_ENV
RACK_ENV
WSGI_ENV
NODE_ENV
PASSENGER_APP_ENV**

Example nginx conf:

```
    http {
    passenger_root /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@app/gems/passenger-4.0.29;
    passenger_ruby /home/user/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.0@app/ruby;
    passenger_app_env development;
}
```

Comment: this is true answer..:)

Comment: This can also be done using the PASSENGER_APP_ENV environment variable for containerized solutions. [See the Passenger documentation for more info](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker#application-environment-name-rails_env-node_env-etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rack_env` directive to set the rails env as described here in passenger for nginx documentation

[6.16. Rack and Rails >= 3 specific options](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#RackEnv)

If you are on rails 1.x or 2.x, you can use `rails_env` directive

Comment: rails_env, rack_env do not work for me, still only development environment

Comment: @static post your problem with `nginx` config as a separate question