# Rails - switch environment to production automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing a project in rails, and i just run this project in console by following command:

```
$ rails server
```

But it runs in **development** mode. I want when i run "rails server", it runs in **production** mode, what script must i edit to set the environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy:

```
rails server RAILS_ENV=production
```

Or:

```
rails s -e production
```

Or you meant without this extra thing? If that so, it depends on which server you use. You can install [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) for example, and add config file, in which you can specify the default environment.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083881/nginx-passenger-rails-where-to-set-rails-env) could help in case of set rails env for ngnx or passenger.

Comment: then you should [modify nginx config file](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerAppEnv)

Answer (score 0):

All the possible operations on the rails server

- -p port: Specify the port to run on
- -b ip: Bind to a specific IP address
- -e name: Use a specific Rails environment (like production)
- -d: Run in daemon mode
- -h: Display a help message with all command-line options